# How to add a link that opens a different pdf in a new window?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I tried this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[pdfnewwindow=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{run:main.pdf}{This is my link}

\end{document}
```

I specified the `pdfnewwindow` option according to the [hyperref documentation](https://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html).

However, the document is open in the same window and there is no way to go back to the original pdf.

I am working in **Ubuntu 16.04** and my pdf viewer is **Okular**. I tried to crawl through every possible option of okular, but there is nothing preventing multiple instances.

Comment: This works for me under Linux, Acrobat Reader 9.5.5 (the latest version available for Linux, as far as I know)

Comment: You can also use \href[pdfnewwindow]{filename}{anchor} but you may need to set \hyperbaseurl

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the following setting

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Also, instead of using `\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow}`, you can press `<Ctrl> key` while clicking on the link, to open the file in a new window.